# RxJS Observable: Emit every specific change in the array

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a list of user IDs, and for each user in the list I want to retrieve extra information. 
So I want to know when the list changes, but also when the information of each user changes.
For example:

- name: Anna, age:28
- name: Peter, age:23
- name: Paul, age 21

If Anna's age changes I want to be able to update the list, and if another user is added to the list I also want to keep track of that.

This is what I've done:

```
private getUserData(userId:string):Observable<User>{...}

let userIds$:Observable<string[]> = getUserIds();

let users$ = userIds$.flatMap(x=>x)   //get the string[]
                     .map(userId => this.getUserData(chatId)) //for each ID get the data
                     .mergeAll();

users$.subscribe(x =>{console.log(x)});
```

This kind of does what I want, but my problem is that every time the list is updated (add elements, or remove), each element in the list subscribes again for changes.
So for example, if I add and 2 elements to the list, and then I update Anna's age, I receive the object Anna 3 times.

For what I've read probably switchMap would fix it, but I've tried using it, and I haven't been able to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: You could always use an object instead of an array and then simply convert it to an array for display purposes. When you could simply replace with their updated versions based on their keys. You might use `reduce` instead of `mergeAll`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

What you need is to emit a value which is a difference between the current and previous list of objects.

Creating a diff can be achieved by using `lodash`'s [`difference`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#difference) function.

Let's assume that the structure of data looks like this:

```
[
  { name: 'Anna', age: 28 },
  { name: 'Peter', age: 23 },
  { name: 'Paul', age: 21 },
]
```

There can be many ways to answer your question but the solution I came up is:

1. Store list in a variable which shouldn't be accessible from the outside.
2. Create one `BehaviorSubject` which will emit the whole array when changed and `Observable` emitting the difference.
3. Create functions which will modify the array and tell `BehaviorSubject` that we have a new array.

> **EDIT:** If somebody reading this has the ambition to create a fully reactive solution, consider using `scan` operator to contain the
>   state with whole functionality in one stream. (spoiler: you'll reinvent redux what isn't a bad thing). The example here was written this way for the sake of simplicity.

I won't try to emulate your implementation (you're fetching data from server API) but I'll give you a pattern which you can take inspiration from.

```
const userList = {
  current: [],
  previous: [],
};

const userListChanged$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(userList.current);
const userListDifference$ = userListChanged$.map(current => {
  return _.difference(current, userList.previous);
});

function currentToPrevious() {
  userList.previous = [].concat(userList.current);
}

function addUser(name, age) {
  currentToPrevious();
  userList.current.push({name, age});
  userListChanged$.next(userList.current);
}

function modifyUser(index, object) {
  currentToPrevious();
  userList.current[index] = Object.assign({}, userList.current[index], object);
  userListChanged$.next(userList.current);
}

userListChanged$.subscribe(value => console.log('list', value));
userListDifference$.subscribe(value => console.log('diff', value));

addUser('Peter', 29);
addUser('Tom', 30);
addUser('Anna', 21);
modifyUser(2, { age: 20 });
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/MichalCafe/n20yzcd8/1/)

`userListDifference$` output:

> [ { name: 'Peter', age: 29 } ]
>
> [ { name: 'Tom', age: 30 } ]
>
> [ { name: 'Anna', age: 21 } ]
>
> [ { name: 'Anna', age: 20 } ]

`userListChanged$` output:

> [ { name: 'Peter', age: 29 } ]
>
> [ { name: 'Peter', age: 29 }, { name: 'Tom', age: 30 } ]
>
> [ { name: 'Peter', age: 29 }, { name: 'Tom', age: 30 }, { name: 'Anna', age: 21 } ]
>
> [ { name: 'Peter', age: 29 }, { name: 'Tom', age: 30 }, { name: 'Anna', age: 20 } ]

Comment: Wow, thanks for your solution, it looks like it wasn't as trivial as I thought it would be.

Comment: No worries and welcome to Stack Overflow! If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted.